# Android Kotlin - detect / listen when NestedScrollView stops scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

This is what I have so far:

```
holder.scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
    Log.d(tagg, "$scrollY")
})
```

I want to detect when scrolling stops and then get the `scrollY`, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is how I solved it:

```
private var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
private fun lastPosUpdate(memeID: Long, scrollPos: Int){

    if(countDownTimer != null){
        countDownTimer!!.cancel()
    }

    countDownTimer = object: CountDownTimer(300, 300) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            Log.d(tagg, "scroll finished")
        }
    }
    countDownTimer!!.start()
}



holder.scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
        lastPosUpdate(meme.id, scrollY)
    })
```

Comment: More better answer which will tell both STATE_SCROLL or STATE_IDLE found here: [link](https://edu.masoomyf.com/2022/09/fixed-android-detect-scrollview-stop.html)